# how to allow traffic to domain to go to https except subdomains

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, traffic

I have a site that directs all traffic to a https version of my website. 
The following code allows that to happen in the `.htaccess` file. How do I ammend it to allow access to my sub domains, as my subdomains get blocked with the code below?

```bash
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

It is applied to this website http://www.asisa.org/. I need access to http://stage.access.org.za/ but the above code is preventing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to add a condition to state that the redirect should only occur on the main domain, whether `www.` is used or not. Add the following just above the rule:

```bash
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?asisa\.org\.za$ [NC]
```

This will ensure that any subdomains, such as http://stage.asisa.org.za/ do not have HTTPS forced when accessed.

> <sub>**Note:** You seem to have conflicted between *asisa.org* and *asisa.org.za* - I have used the latter as the site appears to be for a South African organisation.</sub>